# Application working on emulator but not on mobile

Tags: android, android-emulator

i have developed an application  which uses TTS. it is running fine in emulator when i install it on the mobile it is trying to connect to market and saying "the application has stopped unexpectedly" and asking for force close.where am i going wrong? someone please help me to sort out this problem..

Comment: i have developed it for API level 8 ( android 2.2 )and running on android 2.3 in my mobile. will that be a problem?

Comment: Please post the logcat of the exception, it will make solving your problem much easier.

Comment: how can i post it,it has problem in mobile. where can i get the logcat in mobile..

Comment: Open the DDMS under <your-android-sdk-folder>/tools/ddms.bat, there you'll see your device icon on the left side of the screen. Click on it and you'll see the logcat in the lower part of the screen.

Comment: Post your logcat, you can get logcat view from windows menu >> show view >> other >> log cat.

Comment: :how can i find the logcat in the mobile i am not gettng. please be patient,i dont know where it is and i need to solve it

Comment: @Egor how can i view it on the mobile. i think the problem is with the  tts system. can u tell me how to check whether there is tts in my mobile. and how to install it if it is not there,my mobile is LG optimus p500

Comment: Just plug your phone via USB into your computer and you shall see its logcat inside DDMS. The other method is to install an application such as Catlog and read your logs directly on device.

Comment: i have found out the problem, it is with tts. because tts is not present in it, it is trying to install it and connecting to market. but because the manifest does not have proper permissions to install, i think it is getting problem.i am installing it,if it is not i will try log cat

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Before you run the application go through your mobile that weather TTS is present there or not. Then run the app. I hope it surely work

Comment: my mobile is LG optimus p500,how can i check whether TTS is there in my mobile. how can i install if it is not there...